# how to allow manager to see a component joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

I'm creating a new joomla component.

I've compressed the component in a zip file and installed it, everything works fine and I can see the component in components menu (in the back-end off-course) in when I log in as super user. the problem is when I log in as a manger I can't see the component in that menu, nevertheless I can access it if I point my browser directly to the component url.

It's a very simple component (no config or access.xml) I just want both mangers and super user to see the component in the menu.

Comment: You need to set permission for the manager group from the global cofiguration

Comment: You should always include a config.xml in your component. Just copy one of the core ones and change the name of the component. Also you should always do an access check to prevent direct entry of a url, do you really want unauthorized people looking?

Comment: It includes componentname.xml which contains the component name and I already prevented direct entry, everything is fine but the component doesn't appear in the component menu in the manger back-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config.xml you'll have to add this-

```
<fieldset
        name="permissions"
        label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL"
        description="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_DESC"
        >

        <field
            name="rules"
            type="rules"
            label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL"
            class="inputbox"
            filter="rules"
            validate="rules"
            component="com_component"
            section="component" />
    </fieldset>
```

And there will an `access.xml` file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access component="com_component">
    <section name="component">
        <action name="core.admin" title="JACTION_ADMIN" description="JACTION_ADMIN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.manage" title="JACTION_MANAGE" description="JACTION_MANAGE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.create" title="JACTION_CREATE" description="JACTION_CREATE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.delete" title="JACTION_DELETE" description="JACTION_DELETE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit" title="JACTION_EDIT" description="JACTION_EDIT_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.state" title="JACTION_EDITSTATE" description="JACTION_EDITSTATE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="category">
        <action name="core.create" title="JACTION_CREATE" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="core.delete" title="JACTION_DELETE" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit" title="JACTION_EDIT" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.state" title="JACTION_EDITSTATE" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_EDITSTATE_DESC" />
    </section>
</access>
```

Read more-
http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_ACL_rules_to_your_component

Hope this will help.